# how to use multiple dockerfiles for single application

Tags: python, docker

I am using a centos os base image and installing python3 with the following dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker

ARG USER=dsadmin
ARG HOMEDIR=/home/${USER}

RUN yum clean all \
    && yum update -q -y -t \
    && yum install file -q -y

RUN useradd -s /bin/bash -d ${HOMEDIR} ${USER} 
RUN export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

# install Development Tools to get gcc
RUN yum groupinstall -y "Development Tools"

# install python development so that pip can compile packages
RUN yum -y install epel-release && yum clean all \
    && yum install -y python34-setuptools \
    && yum install -y python34-devel

# install pip
RUN easy_install-3.4 pip

# install virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper
RUN pip3 install virtualenv \
    && pip3 install virtualenvwrapper \
    && pip3 install pandas

# # install django
# RUN pip3 install django

USER ${USER}
WORKDIR ${HOMEDIR}
```

I build and tag the above as follows:

```
docker build . --label validation --tag validation
```

I then need to add a `.tar.gz` file to the home directory. This file contains all the python scripts I maintain. This file will change frequently. If I add it to the dockerfile above, python is installed every time I change the `.gz` file. This adds a lot of time to development. As a workaround, I tried creating a second dockerfile file that uses the above image as the base and then just adds the `.tar.gz` file on it.

```
FROM validation:latest

ARG USER=dsadmin
ARG HOMEDIR=/home/${USER}


ADD code/validation_utility.tar.gz ${HOMEDIR}/.


USER ${USER}
WORKDIR ${HOMEDIR}
```

After that if I run docker image and do an ls, all the files in the folder have a owner of `games`.

```
-rw-r--r--  1     501 games   35785 Nov  2 21:24 Validation_utility.py
```

To fix the above, I added the following lines to the second docker file:

```
ADD code/validation_utility.tar.gz ${HOMEDIR}/.    
RUN chown -R ${USER}:${USER} ${HOMEDIR} \
        && chmod +x ${HOMEDIR}/Validation_utility.py
```

but I get the error:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/home/dsadmin/Validation_utility.py': Operation not permitted
```

The goal is to have two docker files. The users will run the first docker file to install centos and python dependencies. The second dockerfile will install the custom python scripts. If the scripts change, they will just run the second docker file again. Is that the right way to think about docker? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that the right way to think about docker?

This is the easy part of your question. Yes. You're thinking about the proper way to structure your Dockerfiles, reuse them, and keep your image builds efficient. Good job.

As for *the error* you're receiving, I'm less confident in answering why the ADD command is un-tarballing your tar.gz as the `games` user. I'm not nearly as familiar with CentOS. That's the start of the problem. `dsadmin`, as a regular non-privileged user, can't change ownership of files he doesn't own. Since this un-tarballed script is owned by `games`, the `chown` command fails.

I used your Dockerfiles and got the same issue on MacOS.

You can get around this by, well, not using ADD. Which is funny because local tarball extraction is [the one use case](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) where Docker thinks you should prefer ADD over COPY.

```
COPY code/validation_utility.tar.gz ${HOMEDIR}/.
RUN tar -xvf validation_utility.tar.gz
```

Properly extracts the tarball and, since `dsadmin` was the user at the time, the contents come out properly owned by `dsadmin`.

(An uglier route might be to switch the USER to root to set permissions, then set it back to `dsadmin`. I think this is icky, but it's an option.)